# jQuery - remove part of value

Tags: jquery

I have a select box, which have options like this:

```
 <option value='clicks-500' class='mini' data-price='4'>500 Clicks</option>
 <option value='clicks-1000' class='mini' data-price='7'>1000 Clicks</option>
 <option value='clicks-2000' class='mini' data-price='13'>2000 Clicks</option>
 <option value='clicks-10000' class='mini' data-price='60'>10000 Clicks</option>
```

as you can see, the values are in this format: "clicks-xxx"

My question is, how can I remove the "clicks-" so it only leaves the numbers. Currently, I have this piece of code, that takes the entire value.

```
$('#clicks').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: Instead of giving value='clicks-500', just give value='500' because "clicks-" is same in all the option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `clicks-` with `.replace()`

```
$('#clicks').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value.replace("clicks-","") ); // or $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: Or use `this.value.substr(7)` to avoid Regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#clicks').on('change', function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace("clicks-",''));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clicks').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val().split("-")[1]);
});
```

Try on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXSUB/)

With said above, If you need the value without 'click-', why use it in first place, use the number as both value and text for the option.